# TeamCity (msbuild) doesn't build project

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, teamcity

I try launch TeamCity. I managed build Android project local with MSBuild and other build project in local command line, but when I insert this command to TeamCity steps, I have a problem with building.

My steps:

1. cd /d C:\Program Files\Mono\bin
2. mono nuget.exe restore D:\Analytics\mob\mob.sln
3. cd /d D:\Analytics\mob\
4. msbuild /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release mob.sln (This step doesn't build in Teamcity, but build in command line)
5. cd /d D:\Analytics\mob\mob\mob.Droid\
6. msbuild /t:PackageForAndroid /p:Configuration=Release mob.Droid.csproj
7. jarsigner -verbose -sigalg md5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore D:\maximarkets.keystore -storepass 123456 D:\Analytics\mob\mob\mob.Droid\bin\Release\maximarkets.analytics.apk publishingdoc
8. cd /d C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\25.0.1
9. zipalign -f -v 4  D:\Analytics\mob\mob\mob.Droid\bin\Release\maximarkets.analytics.apk D:\maximarkets.analytics.apk
10. cd /d C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools
11. emulator -avd Nexus_5_API_23
12. mono D:\Analytics\mob\packages\NUnit.2.6.4\bin\nunit-console.exe  D:\Analytics\mob\UI_Test_CrossPlatform\bin\Release\UI_Test_CrossPlatform.dll
    -run="UI_Test_CrossPlatform.Tests(Android)" -xml D:\testresults.xml

Full logs: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6335YasDBf8NkMyTWFZOU5pUVk

Comment: You didn't made the build log available for public - if I try to view it google says I don't have the rights...

Comment: Please include relevant information in the Question and not in some off-site resource that can disappear at any point. Also, I highly suggest you use something like Cake or Fake to create your build script. This way you can also validate the build script locally among other advantages.